# Fetch name of the user which id number is given in ListView (React Native-Firebase)

Tags: reactjs, listview, typescript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I really searched for this problem and I could not find anything. Maybe I don't know how should I search. I don't know the name of my problem. Maybe I think like sql structure mind.

I have movie fetching app and commenting on movies. I have database like that:

```
movieId0550: {
      comments: {

         XerqoıasYye.. : {
           comment: 'this is comment',
           user: userId45aqqwuwqh
       },

         DfgakYjsk.. : {
           comment: 'this is comment2',
           user: userId7jsus
       }
    }
}


users: {
     userUid45aqq... : {
            name: 'Jack Daniel'
            }
}
```

I list comments in a listview. And I want to write every user name while I am listing the comment.

So I must fetch user while every item is listed.

My list view is like that. Just look at the CommentName component. It is the component which prints the name of every user:

```
<List
            dataArray={this.props.comments} 
            renderRow={data =>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onLongPress={() => this.popUpDelete(data.uid)}>
              <ListItem avatar>
                <Left>
                  <Thumbnail source={{ uri: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/1065-IMG_2529.jpg' }} />
                </Left>
                <Body>
                  <Text>{data.comment}</Text>
                  <Text numberOfLines={3} note>{data.comment}</Text>
                </Body>
                <Right>
                  <CommentName userId={data.userId} />
                </Right>
              </ListItem>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        }
        />
```

In CommentName component, I try to fetch data in componentDidMount...I know it looks like stupid but I can't set the logic and just trying some ways. My CommentName component:

```
    class CommentName extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { name: 'nsull' };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.userId);
        const ref = firebase.database().ref(`users/${this.props.userId}`);
        return () => {
            ref.once('value', (snapshot) => {
            this.setState({ name: snapshot.val().name });
        });
    };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View><Text>{this.state.name}</Text></View>
        );
    }
}

export default CommentName;
```

So I have a few questions:

- Is my database structure true? I've started to think that I make mistakes and I imagine like it is sql database.
- How can I fetch name of the user in a list view?

Answer (score 0):

1. Comments should be an array.
2. You can access user data by putting them inside comments, like:

   ```
   comments: [
       {
           id: 1,
           comment: "Comment A",
           user: {
               name: "A",
           },
       },
       {
           id: 2,
           comment: "Comment B",
           user: {
               name: "B",
           },
       },
     ]
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I thougt doing like that but what if the user changes his personal Info later? It will show the user's old name

Comment: If user changes his info, then when he back to this page, the comments data will reload too, and the user field will update too.

Comment: Sorry i cant understand.we are pushing the current name of the user when he comment. How will the name change when the user change his username in the users collection?

Comment: The user field inside comments array was read from users collection. Every comment get a user_id, you can read user's info by user_id.So when user changes his info, whenever you access your comments data, it's up to date.

Comment: So that s my question. How can i read user's Info by user ID while i am printing comments? Should i fetch the Info of user while every comment is rendering?

Comment: Sorry i dont know much about firebase. You should follow the [firebase guids](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/). A sql example would be: `SELECT * FROM Comments c INNER JOIN user u ON c.user_id = u.id`

Comment: yep i allready know the sql way. maybe my problem is still imagining as sql way. thank you anyway